# Python-2.7.10 Password GUI not working

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Working on a Python 2.7.10 program, for a password gui but it is giving the error that Application is not defined. I am not sure if there is something wrong with Class Application(Frame) or app = Application(root), because it ask for me to define Application but I don't why they would ask me.

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def _init_(self, master):
        Frame._init_(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.instruction = Label(self, text = "Enter the password")
        self.instruction.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
        self.password = Entry(self)
        self.password.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.submit_button = Button(self, text = "Submit", commmand = self.reveal)
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.text = Text(self, width = 35, height =  5, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
    def reveal(self):
        content = self.password.get()

        if content == "password":
            message = "You have the order"

        else:
            message = "Access denied."
            self.text.delete(0.0, END)
            self.text.insert(0.0, message)

root = Tk()
root.title("Password")
root.geometry("250x150")
app= Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your indentation is incorrect. The `def`s are at the same indentation level as `class Application(Frame)`. With or without fixing the indentation issues, this code won't give the error you say it gives. Please give us runnable code that actually produces the error you say it does.

Comment: There should be two `_` in `__init__`

Comment: I would recommend putting a space between `app` and `=`. Also, could you post the _exact_ error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed your code, here it is:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.instruction = Label(self, text = "Enter the password")
        self.instruction.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)
        self.password = Entry(self)
        self.password.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.submit_button = Button(self, text = "Submit", command = self.reveal)
        self.submit_button.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.text = Text(self, width = 35, height =  5, wrap = WORD)
        self.text.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    def reveal(self):

        content = self.password.get()

        if content == "password":
            message = "You have the order"

        else:
            message = "Access denied."

        self.text.delete(0.0, END)
        self.text.insert(0.0, message)

root = Tk()
root.title("Password")
root.geometry("250x150")
app= Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Your problems were:

- You used _init_ instead of __init__
- Typo of "commmand" instead of "command"
- Last two lines of procedure reveal in Application were incorrectly indented (logic error, not syntax or run-time)

It wasn't really clear what your question was to be honest and I just did this in Python 3.4.3 and made changes so that it should run in Python 2.7.10. I hope that helps.

Comment: If you like it you could +1 my answer (please) :D